# How to open application from list of Installed Application [Android]

Tags: android, arraylist

SOLVED :
**I was splitting the voice command .if user says "Open Browser", i was splitting it
with "Open", so the "Browser" keyword was containing space before it.
i splitted it with "Open " & it worked.. This silly mistake made to me to spend whole day on this ..**

I am trying to Open a Specific app from the list which has the Installed apps details.
To be specific , i m using it with RecognizerIntent , means if i say  "calculator" , then
it should open calculator App.

i have done the following to get the list of installed apps :

```
PackageManager pm ;
 List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps;
 pm =  getPackageManager();
 installedApps = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

After getting installed app in List , i loop through the list to find out if the app which i need is present or not as following :

```
 for(ApplicationInfo ai : installedApps)
    {                           
     String appName = ai.loadLabel(pm).toString().toLowerCase();
     if(appName.equals(AppSearch[1)) //AppSearch[1] contains the result of speech i.e calculator
     {
       Intent openApp = new Intent(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ai.packageName));
       startActivity(openApp);
       openApp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

     }
    }
```

The problem is it doesn't goes into the above "if" condition..
if i simply print the application's name in "for" loop then it shows all the names,
but then why i m not able to compare it & then open it ??
What am i doing wrong please guide me in this .. thanks )

Comment: Plese show appName examples, and AppSearch[1] value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For speech recognition, I would not recommend expecting the result to be 100% accurate, especially with app names. Moreover, from your comment, it seems you don't want to check whether the strings equal, but if the app name contains the voice command, which makes a big difference.

If you just want to check whether the voice result is containes in the app name, use

```
appName.contains(AppSearch[1]);
```

Comment: That doesn't works as well .. i want to check if the app from voice command is installed ? if installed then open it using it's intent.

Comment: Post AppSearch[1]'s content and the app name as returned by ApplicationInfo.

Comment: Also, as mentioned in my question, you cannot expect App names to be recognized correctly, because most of them are no common words.

Comment: AppSearch[1] contains "browser" through the voice command & the installedApp list also has the "browser" lable/app name in it.. still the code is not working ... i m trying this on common apps like calculator , camera etc... they are general apps

Comment: Are you using contain? The equals check in the code you posted will only work if the name is _exactly_ the same.

Comment: If you are using contain, and the app name contains the voice command, it HAS TO work. You must have a bug somewhere else.